# Keycloak jetty adapter cannot be installed in Apache Karaf

Tags: jetty, keycloak, apache-karaf

I use Apache Karaf 4.2.8. I installed keycloak osgi features. I could configure authentication for karaf shell with keycloak using keycloak-jaas feature.

Now I want to configure authentication for my services under /cxf context.

I configured pax-web context so login-method is KEYCLOAK.

But I have to install keycloak-jetty-adapter as well, so it could be integrated. But when I try to install that feature I receive an error.

```
trun()> feature:install keycloak-jetty9-adapter
```

> org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve
>   root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=keycloak-jetty9-adapter; type=karaf.feature;
>   version="[8.0.1,8.0.1]";
>   filter:="(&(osgi.identity=keycloak-jetty9-adapter)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=8.0.1)(version<=8.0.1))" [caused by: Unable to resolve keycloak-jetty9-adapter/8.0.1: missing
>   requirement [keycloak-jetty9-adapter/8.0.1] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=jetty; type=karaf.feature; version="[9.2.0,9.3.0)"] at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:392)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:378)
>   at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:332)
>   at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:388)
>   at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1058)
>   at
>   org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:994)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve
>   keycloak-jetty9-adapter/8.0.1: missing requirement
>   [keycloak-jetty9-adapter/8.0.1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=jetty;
>   type=karaf.feature; version="[9.2.0,9.3.0)" at
>   org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1343)
>   ... 12 more Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing
>   requirement [root] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=keycloak-jetty9-adapter; type=karaf.feature;
>   version="[8.0.1,8.0.1]";
>   filter:="(&(osgi.identity=keycloak-jetty9-adapter)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=8.0.1)(version<=8.0.1))" [caused by: Unable to resolve keycloak-jetty9-adapter/8.0.1: missing
>   requirement [keycloak-jetty9-adapter/8.0.1] osgi.identity;
>   osgi.identity=jetty; type=karaf.feature; version="[9.2.0,9.3.0)"]

If not to install that adapter, then I cannot reach my service (I receive 403 Forbidden) as it is protected via pax-web but authentication is impossible.

It seems that jetty within karaf is embedded and does not contain all features, which does not allow me to install jetty adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [release notes for Apache Karaf 4.2.8](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311140&version=12346100), Karaf is using Jetty 9.4.22, which seems to be outside of your range in the error message `version="[9.2.0,9.3.0)"`

You'll either need to upgrade Keycloak to one that support Jetty 9.4.x
or downgrade Karaf to one that supports the same version of Jetty that Keycloak uses.

Comment: you are right. I also checked the features.xml for keycloak and it only supports 9.2 and 9.3. 
Actually there is a part in keycloak which is for 9.4. But for some reason, it is commented and that's why is not available.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/8.0.1/distribution/adapters/osgi/features/src/main/resources/features.xml#L57

As your answer is the current reason of the failure, so, I mention it as a solution. And I hope that keycloak will uncomment that part of code in features somewhen.